# Sub-class must implement the PagerTabStripDataSource viewControllers(for:) method in XLPagerTabStripe library

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I've updated Swift project from Swift 2 to Swift 4 and I'm facing this issue.
Before migration it worked fine in Swift 2.
But after migration error occurred

> Sub-class must implement the PagerTabStripDataSource viewControllers(for:) method

As I found solution on google, Some people suggest to add this delegate.

```
func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
    return IndicatorInfo(title: "BASIC INFO")
}
```

I added this function but this doesn't help.
Can anyone please help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed this function.

```
override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
...
}
```

When I add this function, it worked fine.
It was like this before.

```
func viewControllersForPagerTabStrip(_ pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this link](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/blob/master/Migration.md) to the GitHub page for XLPagerTapStrip. Many names changed from swift 2 to swift 3 and the function that the error says you need is in there, so you'll need to reimplement o rename some functions for it to work.